# Content block became linkable, without any command

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have purchased a premium WordPress theme.

The last block of content on the homepage became linkable, without any (visible) command. I contacted the maker of the theme, and the support answer is that I should fix the HTML errors. I've trashed the box content and created a new one, I've been looking for errors everywhere. Can't really solve this on my own :(

Please take a look at the homepage and tell me how can I solve this linkable piece of content.

http://theculinarycompanion.com/

PS: I'm no coder. Just know the basics.

Thanks

Comment: What sort of framework are you using to build your website? Also, consider splitting your test up into paragraphs, it will be easier for customers to read!

Comment: Thanks Will.
I'm using wordpress, with Betheme.

You're right. The text is too long, of course. Still in the design process :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, but it sounds like maybe there is HTML code in the box which you can't see.

Is there an "HTML view" of the content box which you can edit? You may find the unwanted link is visible from there.

If that doesn't work, try deleting the entire content box and re-creating it from scratch. And be careful about which type of content box you are creating.

Good luck!

Comment: Will, thanks for your input.
It was a <a tag that wasn't closed.
Unfortunately it's hard to see it in the theme.

Solved :)
Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Could you mark my answer as correct by clicking on the tick mark